# mySQL random order query with 1 exception in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm using the following to randomly order a query in Wordpress:

```
$args_projekte = array(
        'post_type' => 'projekt',
        'posts_per_page' => 18,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        );
$query_projekte = new WP_Query($args_projekte);
```

However, I need one recordset with id=191 to ALWAYS be positioned as the 5th recordset in my random query result.

Is this possible? Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This is challenging, but you can do it with the following query:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) param
      order by (id <> 191) desc
     ) t
order by (seqnum < 8) desc,
         (id = 191) desc,
         rand();
```

A pain.  You have to be sure that id 191 is *not* in the first seven rows.  Then, you want to be sure that the random rows before and after do not overlap -- that is why a `union` approach is hard to implement.